# Timing difference/increase different when using `%` vs `&`

Tags: c++, performance

In trying to determine the cache size for a given CPU, I tried to time the memory access to memory/cache like:

```
lengthMod = sizes[i]/sizeof(int)  - 1; // where sizes[i] is something like 1024, 2048 ... 
for (unsigned int k = 0; k < REPS; k++) {
    data[(k * 16) & lengthMod]++;
}

1, 0.52 
4, 0.52 
8, 0.52 
16, 0.52 
32, 0.52 
64, 1.11 // << note the jump in timing. L1 cache size is 32K
128, 1.12 
256, 1.19
```

So I think if the lengthMod is not a power of 2, I cant do this. So I tried doing

```
lengthMod = sizes[i]/sizeof(int);
for (unsigned int k = 0; k < REPS; k++) {
    data[(k * 16) % lengthMod]++;
}

1, 2.67 
4, 2.57 
8, 2.55 
16, 2.51 
32, 2.42 
64, 2.42 // << no jump anymore ...
128, 2.42 
256, 2.42
```

Then I find that the timing increase that I expected is non-existant anymore ... I expected the time to increase but it should apply to all values? So if its `x` seconds when using `&`, I'd expect `~x+c` seconds (where `c` is approximatly constant), but thats not the case, in fact, it reduces the timing difference to non-existant why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is a trade-off of bottlenecks.

- In the first example, you are bottlenecked by your cache bandwidth.
- In the second example, you are bottlenecked by integer division.

Before we continue, let's look at the difference between the two examples:

- In the first case, you use `&` which is a fast bitwise operation.
- In the second case, you use `%` which is very slow division.

Divisions are *very* slow. Modern compilers will try to optimize them when the divisor/modulus is a compile-time constant.

But that's not the case here. ***So you pay the full cost of a hardware division.*** This is why the times in your second example are much slower than the first.

---

With the `&`, the code is fast enough to max out the cache bandwidth. However, with `%`, the code is much slower - not fast enough to keep up with the cache. So you see the same times all the way up.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in second case compiler generates less optimized code (because of "division with remainder").